# Formatting Mindmap in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am wondering if anyone can help me in formatting my mindmap that I have given below so everything is uniform and angles are set according to the number of children in the node? Also, I have tried scaling the Ti*k*Z picture but still failed to bring it all within the margins.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \tikzset{level 1/.append style={sibling angle=50,level distance = 135mm}}
    \tikzset{level 2/.append style={sibling angle=20,level distance = 25mm}}
    \tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.5}}

    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ mindmap, every node/.style=concept, concept color=teal!40,grow cyclic,]

    \node[concept] {Malnutrition}
    child [concept color=purple!40]{    node    {Health Facility}
            child { node    {Inadequate ANC Care} }
            child { node    {Long Distance of Health Care Facility} }
            child { node    {Insufficient Health Service} }
            child { node    {Incomplete Immunization} }
}
    child [concept color=pink!40]{ node     {Morbidity}
            child { node    {Intestinal Diseases} }
            child { node    {Congenital Anomalies} }
}
    child [concept color=green!40]{ node    {Maternal Health}
            child { node {Maternal malnutrition} }
            child { node {Higher Birth order} }
            child { node {Short birth interval} }
            child { node {Adolescent mother} }
}
    child [concept color=red!40]{ node  {Cultural Factors}
            child { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
            child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
            child { node {Early marriage} }
            child { node {Inadequate child care} }
            child { node {Feeding practices} } 
}  
    child [concept color=blue!40]{ node     {Socio-demographic Factors}
            child { node {Caste (ST/SC)} }
            child { node {Illiteracy} }
            child { node {Lack of Awareness about Nutrition} }
            child { node {Occupation} }
            child { node {Low Socio-Economic Status} } 
            child { node {Inadequate access to food} }    
}                                           
    child [concept color=yellow!40]{ node   {Biological Factors}[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
            child { node {Female} }
            child { node {Low Birth Weight} }
            child { node {Age of the Child} }
}                                           
    child [concept color=violet!40]{ node {Environmental Factors}
            child { node {Poor Unsafe Drinking Water} }
            child { node {Poor Personal Hygiene} }
            child { node {Poor Sanitation} }
            child { node {Open Field Defecation} }
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Add the option `scale=0.9` or equivalent to the `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, drawing mind maps seems to be a pain. The results I like. But they seem to require *a lot* of manual tweaking such that if you change anything you have to recode half the map. If `forest` could only draw cyclical trees... !

You could scale the picture, as mentioned in the comments. What I would tend to do would be to 'cheat' and let the map exceed the width of the text body. Usually, mind maps need to be on their own page anyway, so so long as they fit the physical dimensions of the page, I tend to let them flow outside the margins a bit.

Alternatively, you could, for example, use a smaller font for the outer nodes.

At any rate, here - for whatever it is worth - is my attempt at manually squishing the map into places it wants not to go...

[image: managed mind map]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\centering
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [mindmap,
      grow cyclic,
      every node/.style=concept,
      concept color=teal!40,
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/7},
      level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
      ]
      \node [root concept] {Malnutrition}
        child [concept color=purple!40]{
          node    {Health Facility}
          child { node    {Inadequate ANC Care} }
          child { node    {Long Distance of Health Care Facility} }
          child { node    {Insufficient Health Service} }
          child { node    {Incomplete Immunization} }
        }
        child [concept color=pink!40, rotate=-10]{
          node     {Morbidity}
          child { node    {Intestinal Diseases} }
          child { node    {Congenital Anomalies} }
        }
        child [concept color=green!40, rotate=-20]{
          node  {Maternal Health}
          child { node {Maternal malnutrition} }
          child { node {Higher Birth order} }
          child { node {Short birth interval} }
          child { node {Adolescent mother} }
        }
        child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
          node  {Cultural Factors}[counterclockwise from=-115]
          child  { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
          child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
          child { node {Early marriage} }
          child { node {Inadequate child care} }
          child { node {Feeding practices} }
        }
        child [concept color=blue!40, rotate=-7.5]{
          node     {Socio-demographic Factors}
          child { node {Caste (ST/SC)} }
          child { node {Illiteracy} }
          child { node {Lack of Awareness about Nutrition} }
          child { node {Occupation} }
          child { node {Low Socio-Economic Status} }
          child { node {Inadequate access to food} }
        }
        child [concept color=yellow!40, rotate=-5]{
          node   {Biological Factors}%[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
          child { node {Female} }
          child { node {Low Birth Weight} }
          child { node {Age of the Child} }
        }
        child [concept color=violet!40, rotate=-5] {
          node {Environmental Factors}
          child { node {Poor Unsafe Drinking Water} }
          child { node {Poor Personal Hygiene} }
          child { node {Poor Sanitation} }
          child { node {Open Field Defecation} }
        };
  \end{tikzpicture}}\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to draw 1 or 2 specific nodes in rectangular form? Sometimes, the text does not fit well in circle shape node.

Comment: @Sigur If you don't use the `concept` style for a node, then it won't get the default mind-map formatting. But you can also just add to the format by using e.g. `rectangle` in the options to the `node`. At least, that works for me. Did you try it?

Comment: Ow, it works. But it is ugly. It does not fit in the conector. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Well, the circles thing is part of the quirky style of these mind maps. So I guess it isn't that surprising if rectangles don't fit well. Really, it would be nice to have a mind maps library for TikZ that supported the creation of regular mind maps because they are much more efficient in terms of space, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even after 7 years this is really helpful at times. Im wondering if there are any easier ways to draw such mindmaps nowadays.