# Multiple mindmaps representation in perspective

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

The idea of connecting multiple mindmaps corresponds visually to ([here](https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network) and [here for details](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-network/tikz-network.pdf))

[image]
[image]

The integrity (naming, connecting...) of the nodes is kept.

**Problematic**

I try to create a complex Mindmap to describe a course.
However there are multiple levels of complexity i'd like to explain with multiple grids (one above/next to the other) as in [Grids](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/contours-grids/)

[image]

I tried to input the image of the Mindmap in an `includegraphics` but it's not satisfactory since i want to connect nodes from one mindmap to the other.

```
% Author: Rudolf Siegel
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{
    basefont/.style = {font = \LARGE\sffamily},
      timing/.style = {basefont, sloped,above,},
       label/.style = {basefont, align = left},
      screen/.style = {basefont, 
                        black!80, 
                        align = center,
                        minimum size = 6cm, 
                        fill = gray!10, 
                        draw = gray}};
    
  % macro for defining screens
     \newcommand*{\screen}[4]{%
      \begin{scope}[xshift  =#3, yshift = #4,
                  every node/.append style = {yslant = 0.33},
                  yslant = 0.33,
                 local bounding box = #1]
     \node[screen] at (3cm,3cm) {#2};
     \end{scope}
    }   
     % define several screens
     \screen{frame1, fill = blue!40}{\includegraphics[width=9cm]{MWE1.pdf}  
  } {0}{0}
      \screen{frame2, fill = blue!40,opacity=0.5}{
     \includegraphics[width=9cm]{MWE2.pdf}} {150}{-60}
     \coordinate [xshift=750,yshift=-300] (frame6);

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to used a scope and play with the tikzlibrary `positioning` but I get strange results.

Based on this mindmap [MindmapMWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250150/formatting-mindmap-in-tikz) for instance (or just any mindmap), what should be the principle to create the above graph ?

```
MWE1.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [mindmap,
  grow cyclic,
  every node/.style=concept,
  concept color=teal!40,
  level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/4},
  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
  ]
  \node [root concept] {Malnutrition Level 1 analysis}
    child [concept color=purple!40]{
      node    {Health Facility}
      child { node    {Inadequate ANC Care} }
      child { node    {Long Distance of Health Care Facility} }
      child { node    {Insufficient Health Service} }
      child { node    {Incomplete Immunization} }
    }
    child [concept color=pink!40, rotate=-10]{
      node     {Morbidity}
      child { node    {Intestinal Diseases} }
      child { node    {Congenital Anomalies} }
    }
    child [concept color=green!40, rotate=-20]{
      node  {Maternal Health}
      child { node {Maternal malnutrition} }
      child { node {Higher Birth order} }
      child { node {Short birth interval} }
      child { node {Adolescent mother} }
    }
    child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
      node  {Cultural Factors}[counterclockwise from=-115]
      child  { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
      child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
      child { node {Early marriage} }
      child { node {Inadequate child care} }
      child { node {Feeding practices} }
    }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}

MWE2.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [mindmap,
  grow cyclic,
  every node/.style=concept,
  concept color=teal!40,
  level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/4},
  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
  ]
  \node [root concept] {Malnutrition Level 2 analysis}
    child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
      node  {Cultural Factors}[counterclockwise from=-115]
      child  { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
      child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
      child { node {Early marriage} }
      child { node {Inadequate child care} }
      child { node {Feeding practices} }
    }
    child [concept color=blue!40, rotate=-7.5]{
      node     {Socio-demographic Factors}
      child { node {Caste (ST/SC)} }
      child { node {Illiteracy} }
      child { node {Lack of Awareness about Nutrition} }
      child { node {Occupation} }
      child { node {Low Socio-Economic Status} }
      child { node {Inadequate access to food} }
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!40, rotate=-5]{
      node   {Biological Factors}%[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
      child { node {Female} }
      child { node {Low Birth Weight} }
      child { node {Age of the Child} }
    }
    child [concept color=violet!40, rotate=-5] {
      node {Environmental Factors}
      child { node {Poor Unsafe Drinking Water} }
      child { node {Poor Personal Hygiene} }
      child { node {Poor Sanitation} }
      child { node {Open Field Defecation} }
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, without an MWE, how can we do anything?

Comment: I inputed a MWE1.tex and MWE2.tex that might be easier to work on. I just try to get the general idea of how to input the mindmap on a grid.

Comment: @JouleV I precised my question with MWE.

Comment: I guess it will be somewhat nontrivial to make you happy. You can use the `3d` library to project the mindmaps on the planes but this requires `transform shape` which more or less destroys the mindmaps. So you will have to define your own transformations which will be nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you marmot! Knowing it's not trivial for you is enough to consider another approach. A bientôt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw this configuration at the expense of putting the mind maps into `\savebox`es. If you go this way, you will lose the possibility to name nodes and connecting them with lines. More precisely, this will become harder. I was able to "recover" the coordinates to some extent by reading off the transformation matrix and shifts, and by applying them to the untransformed coordinates. (Remember that the `tikz` coordinates are always global, so there is some information even if we use `\saveboxes` because at the moment the `\savebox` gets "filled" the coordinates get stored/broadcasted.) The result is far from perfect but you can now say

```
\draw[blue,thick,reconstruct=from HF to CF];
```

where `CF` and `HF` are named nodes that are in the mind maps. Do not expect too much.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,3d,backgrounds,calc}
\newsavebox\MindMapA
\newsavebox\MindMapB
\begin{document}
\savebox\MindMapA{\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,transparency group,
  grow cyclic,
  every node/.style=concept,
  concept color=teal!40,
  level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/4},
  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
  ]
  \node [root concept] {Malnutrition Level 1 analysis}
    child [concept color=purple!40]{
      node [alias=HF]   {Health Facility}
      child { node    {Inadequate ANC Care} }
      child { node    {Long Distance of Health Care Facility} }
      child { node    {Insufficient Health Service} }
      child { node    {Incomplete Immunization} }
    }
    child [concept color=pink!40, rotate=-10]{
      node [alias=Morb]    {Morbidity}
      child { node    {Intestinal Diseases} }
      child { node    {Congenital Anomalies} }
    }
    child [concept color=green!40, rotate=-20]{
      node  {Maternal Health}
      child { node {Maternal malnutrition} }
      child { node {Higher Birth order} }
      child { node {Short birth interval} }
      child { node {Adolescent mother} }
    }
    child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
      node  {Cultural Factors}[counterclockwise from=-115]
      child  { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
      child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
      child { node {Early marriage} }
      child { node {Inadequate child care} }
      child { node {Feeding practices} }
    }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\savebox\MindMapB{\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,transparency group,
  grow cyclic,
  every node/.style=concept,
  concept color=teal!40,
  level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/4},
  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
  ]
  \node [root concept] {Malnutrition Level 2 analysis}
    child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
      node [alias=CF]  {Cultural Factors}[counterclockwise from=-115]
      child  { node {Adverse cultural practice} }
      child { node {Traditional beliefs} }
      child { node {Early marriage} }
      child { node {Inadequate child care} }
      child { node {Feeding practices} }
    }
    child [concept color=blue!40, rotate=-7.5]{
      node  [alias=Socio]   {Socio-demographic Factors}
      child { node {Caste (ST/SC)} }
      child { node {Illiteracy} }
      child { node {Lack of Awareness about Nutrition} }
      child { node {Occupation} }
      child { node {Low Socio-Economic Status} }
      child { node {Inadequate access to food} }
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!40, rotate=-5]{
      node   {Biological Factors}%[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
      child { node {Female} }
      child { node {Low Birth Weight} }
      child { node {Age of the Child} }
    }
    child [concept color=violet!40, rotate=-5] {
      node {Environmental Factors}
      child { node {Poor Unsafe Drinking Water} }
      child { node {Poor Personal Hygiene} }
      child { node {Poor Sanitation} }
      child { node {Open Field Defecation} }
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\tikzset{halo/.style={insert path={
([xshift=-2em,yshift=-2em]#1.south west) --
([xshift=2em,yshift=-2em]#1.south east) --
([xshift=2em,yshift=2em]#1.north east) --
([xshift=-2em,yshift=2em]#1.north west) -- cycle}}}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{105}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4,transform shape]
  \node[opacity=0.8] (MMA) {\usebox\MindMapA};
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!30,opacity=0.2,halo=MMA]; 
   \end{scope}
  %\pgftransforminvert
  \pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmpe}{\tmpf}
   \begin{scope}[reconstruct/.style args={from #1 to #2}{insert path={
   let \p1=(#1),\p2=(#2),
    \n1={\tmpa*\x1+\tmpc*\y1+\tmpe},\n2={\tmpb*\x1+\tmpd*\y1+\tmpf},
    \n3={\tmpa*\x2+\tmpc*\y2-\tmpe},\n4={\tmpb*\x2+\tmpd*\y2-\tmpf} 
    in (\n1,\n2) -- (\n3,\n4)
   }}]
    \draw[blue,thick,reconstruct=from HF to CF];
    \draw[red,thick,shorten <=6pt,reconstruct=from Morb to Socio];
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  %

  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-4,transform shape]
  \node[opacity=0.8] (MMB) {\usebox\MindMapB};
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!30,opacity=0.2,halo=MMB]; 
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe that we draw the connections before we place the mindmap in the front, which "proves" that the coordinates get set when invoking the `\savebox` commands, and not when actually using them. Please note also that, for this to work, we need to shift the planes symmetrically, i.e. when one plane has `canvas is yz plane at x=4,` then the other one has to come with `canvas is yz plane at x=-4,` (and not, say, `x=-6`).

Comment: The idea of connecting the nodes of different mind maps was quite appealing in terms of pedagogy :)

Comment: I'm working on an alternative solution in 2D and have no doubt you'll be as always super helpful.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I have added something that allows one to approximately recover nodes. Far from perfect but perhaps a step in the right direction.

Comment: As usual. Wow!!

Comment: I'll play around with your code to get the grids more vertically so that I can see better the connections. Merci marmot! :)